# Apache Flink : Batch Mode failing for Datastream API's with exception `IllegalStateException: Checkpointing is not allowed with sorted inputs.`

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, watermark, flink-batch

A continuation to this : [Flink : Handling Keyed Streams with data older than application watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795679/flink-handling-keyed-streams-with-data-older-than-application-watermark)

based on the suggestion, I have been trying to add support for Batch in the same Flink application which was using the Datastream API's.

The logic is something like this :

```
streamExecutionEnvironment.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
streamExecutionEnvironment.readTextFile("fileName")
.process(process function which transforms input)
.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy
                .<DetectionEvent>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(orderness)
                .withTimestampAssigner(
                        (SerializableTimestampAssigner<Event>) (event, l) -> event.getEventTime()))
.keyBy(keyFunction)
.window(TumblingEventWindows(Time.of(x days))
.process(processWindowFunction);
```

Based on the public docs, my understanding was that i simply needed to change the source to a bounded one. However the above processing keeps on failing at the event trigger after the windowing step with the below exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Checkpointing is not allowed with sorted inputs.
    at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:193)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.init(OneInputStreamTask.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeRestore(StreamTask.java:552)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:537)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:571)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

The input file contains the historical events for multiple keys. The data for a given key is sorted, but the overall data is not. I have also added an event at the end of each key with the timestamp = MAX_WATERMARK to indicate end of keyed Stream. I tried it for a single key as well but the processing failed with the same exception.

Note: I have not enabled checkpointing.
I have also tried explicitly disabling checkpointing to no avail.

```
env.getCheckpointConfig().disableCheckpointing();
```

EDIT - 1

Adding more details :
I tried changing and using FileSource to read files but still getting the same exception.

```
environment.fromSource(FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineFormat(), path).build(),
WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
"Text File")
```

The first process step and key splitting works. However it fails after that. I tried removing windowing and adding a simple process step but it continues to fail.
There is no explicit Sink. The last process function simply updates a database.

[image: process]
[image: exception]
[image: timeline]
[image: Attaching images in case they help.]

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: There's no need for you to sort the input, or add special watermarks. These are things Flink will do itself when operating in batch mode. Not sure what's wrong; it would help to see the entire job. The problem might be the connectors -- batch mode works best with connectors using the new source and sink interfaces.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, updated the description of original post with additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception can only be thrown if checkpointing is enabled. Perhaps you can a checkpointing interval configured in flink-conf.yaml?

Comment: Turns out that kinesis analytics has check pointing enabled by default (I'm using kinesis analytics to deploy and manage the flink application). Turning it off seems to have done the trick although its leading to a new set of problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157652/apache-flink-with-kinesis-analytics-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-fr