# Apache Flink with Kinesis Analytics : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The fraction of memory to allocate should not be 0

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, watermark, flink-batch, amazon-kinesis-analytics

Background :
I have been trying to setup BATCH + STREAMING in the same flink application which is deployed on kinesis analytics runtime. The STREAMING part works fine, but I'm having trouble adding support for BATCH.

[Flink : Handling Keyed Streams with data older than application watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795679/flink-handling-keyed-streams-with-data-older-than-application-watermark)

[Apache Flink : Batch Mode failing for Datastream API's with exception `IllegalStateException: Checkpointing is not allowed with sorted inputs.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70137863/apache-flink-batch-mode-failing-for-datastream-apis-with-exception-illegalst)

The logic is something like this :

```
The logic is something like this :

streamExecutionEnvironment.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);
streamExecutionEnvironment.fromSource(FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineFormat(), path).build(),
WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
"Text File")
.process(process function which transforms input)
.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy
                .<DetectionEvent>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(orderness)
                .withTimestampAssigner(
                        (SerializableTimestampAssigner<Event>) (event, l) -> event.getEventTime()))
.keyBy(keyFunction)
.window(TumblingEventWindows(Time.of(x days))
.process(processWindowFunction);
```

On doing this I'm getting the below exception :

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(OperatorChain.java:441)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:582)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeRestore(StreamTask.java:562)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:537)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:571)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for WindowOperator_90bea66de1c231edf33913ecd54406c1_(1/1) from any of the 1 provided restore options.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.keyedStatedBackend(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:345)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.streamOperatorStateContext(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:163)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to acquire shared cache resource for RocksDB
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBOperationUtils.allocateSharedCachesIfConfigured(RocksDBOperationUtils.java:306)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.java:426)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.createKeyedStateBackend(EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.lambda$keyedStatedBackend$1(StreamTaskStateInitializerImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.attemptCreateAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.BackendRestorerProcedure.createAndRestore(BackendRestorerProcedure.java:135)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The fraction of memory to allocate should not be 0. Please make sure that all types of managed memory consumers contained in the job are configured with a non-negative weight via `taskmanager.memory.managed.consumer-weights`.
    at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.validateFraction(MemoryManager.java:672)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.computeMemorySize(MemoryManager.java:653)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory(MemoryManager.java:521)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBOperationUtils.allocateSharedCachesIfConfigured(RocksDBOperationUtils.java:302)
    ... 17 more
```

Seems like kinesis-analytics does not allow clients to define a flink-conf.yaml file to define `taskmanager.memory.managed.consumer-weights`. Is there any way around this ?

Comment: What value did you try to set for `taskmanager.memory.managed.consumer-weights` ?

Comment: @DavidAnderson, unfortunately kinesis-analytics does not seem allow clients to define a flink-conf.yaml to override this. Is there anything else that can be done here ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what the underlying cause of this exception is, nor how to make batch processing work on KDA.

You can try this (but I'm not sure KDA will allow it):

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setString("taskmanager.memory.managed.consumer-weights", "put-the-value-here");

StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
  StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(conf);
```